# Virtual Machine (Ubuntu) cannot connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

My host is windows 7 and my guest (virtual machine) is ubuntu. I cannot connect to internet when I am on virtual environment. I am using Oracle VirtualBox. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

1- edit the file " interfaces":

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

2- then make sure this line is in that file :

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

3- run `dhclient`

4- run `ping 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 5):

There are several modes in which you can connect to internet inside from a virtual machine. Easiest is using **NAT**.

Select your **Ubuntu virtual machine** in virtual box manager and go to **settings**. Navigate to **Network** and select **NAT** as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

When you open Ubuntu go to **Network Connection** and go to **Wired** tab and select your connection and **Edit**. Use **Automatic (DHCP)** under **IPv4 Settings**. Also you can check the connect automatically. Then your system will be connected to network every time you open it.

[image]

Comment: did you able to connect?

Comment: It failed to connect.

Comment: is your host network functioning properly? Was the connection established at all in guest? how did you check? usually it should connect if you would able to follow the instruction properly. try restarting the virtual machine and check all the settings once. we need some more info to help you to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes I have followed all ur setting above. I also have restarted the vm.

Comment: which version of virtual box and Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi VB version 4.3.12 and ubuntu is the ubuntu 14.04. I cannot either to drag drop file to my host OS. is it due to firewall of my office? I am installing it on my office pc.

Comment: versions are fine. But it is highly unusual. usually in `NAT` guest uses the network of host without any trouble. I have no clue what is happening to you. I will inform you if I find anything.  drag and drop or sharing the clipboard are different issue. you need to install virtualbox extendtion pack and guest addition for those.

Answer (score 2):

Close Virtual Box

Right click on Virtual Box instance, and select Settings.

On the `Network Tab > Adapter 1`, Select `Bridged Adapter` option to the `Attached to` dropdown .

Start Virtual Box instance

ping `google.com`

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was solved for me by changing a previously selected setting.  When I originally set up VB I configured it to use a wireless connection.  But then wireless for me became unavailable because of my situation, but I had forgotten that I needed to change the setting in VB to use a wired connection instead.

I don't know if this reflects your situation, but here are the steps for changing connection type:

Open VB, go to Settings, Network, Adapter 1, "Name", choose connection type.

Comment: I think this is pretty well covered in the July 2014 answer

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that I couldn't access the Internet from my Ubuntu VM. I forgot that on the host machine (Windows 10 x64) still, an OpenVPN connection was active.

I closed OpenVPN on the Windows machine and it worked again.